# How do I wait for the processes to finish in the SplashActivity ViewModel in compose kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-splashscreen

I used an api called splash api for my application's splash screen and if you know how to use it you need to add a few xml files and images and you also need to add code to the manifest for SplashActivity. I did all of these, the splash screen appears, but I'm having a problem with navigating. I check if the refresh token exists on the splash screen, if there is, I generate a new access token using the refresh token. The classical token operation, however, seems to be asynchronous, so the viewmodel does not wait for my actions and goes directly to the main page without waiting. Normally, if there is a token, it should go directly to the user account page, that is, in the dashbord, if there is no token, it should start from the start screen(main page). I put this logic into code, but as I said, it probably does not wait because it is executed asynchronously and goes directly to the start screen. Could you please review my codes and help me how to solve the problem? By the way, it's just my opinion when I say it doesn't wait because it works asynchronously. I'm not sure about that, you can correct me if I'm wrong.

**here are my codes**

**SplashActivity.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    private val viewModel: SplashScreenViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
            splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.state.collect { state ->
                    // New values! Update the UI
                    val errMsg = "error occurs"
                    if (state.error) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity, errMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    if (state.isRefreshTokenExist) {
                        state.refreshToken?.let {
                            viewModel.refreshAccessToken(it)
                        }
                        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("isTokenExist", true) 
                        // I send to MainAcitivty isTokenExist Boolean 
                        //value to determine which screen to go to
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    
                    } else {
                        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("isTokenExist", false)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            }
            delay(3000L)
        }
    }
}
```

**SplashScreenViewModel.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SplashScreenState())
    val state: StateFlow<SplashScreenState> = _state.asStateFlow()
   
    init {
        getRefreshToken()
    }

    fun refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: String) {

        runBlocking {
            val job = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                try {
                    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                    loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient
                        .Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                        //.authenticator(AuthAuthenticator(tokenManager))
                        .build()

                    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .build()

                    val service = retrofit.create(RegisterService::class.java)

                    val response = service.refreshToken(model = RefreshToken(refreshToken))

                    if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                        val newAccessToken = response.body()?.access_token
                        val newRefreshToken = response.body()?.refresh_token
                        if (newAccessToken != null && newRefreshToken != null) {
                            tokenManager.saveAccessToken(newAccessToken)
                            tokenManager.saveRefreshToken(newRefreshToken)
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            error = true
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            job.join()
        }
    }

    private fun getRefreshToken() {


        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            tokenManager.getRefreshToken().collect { refreshToken ->
                if (refreshToken != null) {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isRefreshTokenExist = true,
                            refreshToken = refreshToken
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

data class SplashScreenState(
    val isRefreshTokenExist: Boolean = false,
    val refreshToken: String? = null,
    val error: Boolean = false,
)
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var navHostController: NavHostController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val isTokenExist:Boolean = intent.getBooleanExtra("isTokenExist",false) 
        // I take the isTokenExist boolean value 
        // from SplashActivity using Intent as you can see above SplashActivity code

        val metrics =  resources.displayMetrics

        ScreenQuery.screenWidth =  (metrics.widthPixels / metrics.density ).toInt()
        ScreenQuery.screenHeight = (metrics.heightPixels / metrics.density ).toInt()

        /*------*/
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this) {

        }

        setContent {

            DiyetkolikTheme {
                navHostController = rememberNavController()
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    RootNavGraph(navHostController = navHostController,isTokenExist)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

---

1. registerLoginNavGraph is StartScreen(main page). it should go if
   token is not exist
2. dashBoardNavGraph is user account page. it should go it token exist

**RootNavGraph.kt**

```
const val ROOT_ROUTE = "route_root"

@Composable
fun RootNavGraph(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    isTokenExist:Boolean
) {

    val sharedViewModel : SharedViewModel = viewModel()
    val startDestination = if(isTokenExist) DASHBOARD_ROUTE else REGISTER_LOGIN_ROUTE

    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        route = ROOT_ROUTE
    )
    {
        registerLoginNavGraph(navHostController,sharedViewModel)
        dashBoardNavGraph(navHostController,sharedViewModel)
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried this solution provided by the [Splash Screen guidelines > Keep the splash screen on-screen for longer periods](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#suspend-drawing)? they stated that if you somehow need 'extra' data you can extend the splash screen duration

Answer (score 0):

you can check token in splash activity. if exist after delay go to main activity (start delay in if (token exist)). in else don't use delay and wait for token api response in view model you can use live data and when get token then go to main

Comment: can you share code so I can understand clearly what you try to say.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).